# Designing an algorithm to calculate the edit distance between two strings

Tags: string, algorithm, big-o, edit, distance

Please consider the following question:

The edit distance of two strings `s` and `t` is the minimum number of single character operations (insert, delete, substitution) needed to convert `s` into `t`. Let `m` and `n` be the length of strings `s` and `t`.

Design an `O(nm)` time and `O(nm)` space algorithm to calculate the edit distance between `s` and `t`.

**My thoughts:**

Isn't it easier to just compare two strings one character at a time:

```
L = maximum(length(s), length(t))
for i in L:
   if i > length(s):
      distance += length(t) - i
      break
   if i > length(t):
      distance += length(s) - i
      break
   if s[i] != t[i]:
      distance += 1
```

If I am wrong, then am I supposed to use the edit distance algorithm table? Is so, how do I design an `O(nm)` time and `O(nm)` space algorithm?

Comment: [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: See also [this tutorial](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeAlgDS/Dynamic/Edit/).

Comment: Clearly your algorithm will fail if s=`ABCDEF` and t=`BCDEFG` (edit distance = 2).

Comment: Hmm, I guess I thought "insert" would be adding " " at the end and "delete" would be the same as substituting one character with " "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Roberto Attias for his answer, but the following is the complete algorithm I am looking for:

```
L1 = length(string1)
L2 = length(string2)
for i in L1:
    table[i][0] = i
for i in L2:
    table[0][i] = i
for i in L1:
    for j in L2:
        m = minimum(table[i-1][j],table[i][j-1])+1
        if s[i] == t[j]: subvalue = 1
        else: subvalue = 0
        table[i][j] = minimum(m, table[i-1][j-1] + subvalue)
return table[L1][L2]
```

The above algorithm follows the strategy of an edit distance algorithm table

Answer (score 1):

Consider the strings `abcd`  and `bcd`. They differ for one deletion, but your approach would count them as distance 4.

What you want to do is find the Longest Common Subsequence. This is a well known problem  and you can google up a lot of code examples about it, with one solution being in fact O (NM).

For example, for strings `abcdqef` and `xybcdzzzef` the LCS is `bcdqef`. consider the subsequence in the two strings:

```
a-bcd-q-ef
xy-bcd-zzz-ef
```

You can transform `a` into `xy` with one modification and one insertion, and `q` into `zzz` with one modification and two insertion. If you think about it, the number of operations required (i.e. distance) is the number of characters in the longest string not belonging to the LCS.

Comment: You missed "q" in your example for string "abcdef"

Comment: What does O(NM) mean? Say if strings are "dog" and "cats", is it O(3 x 4) = O(12) which means algorithm should be less than 12 steps?

Comment: fixed example.
O(NM) means the same thing that in your question, it's an indication of the time/space complexity of the algorithm. "talking about "steps" is not quite correct, you may want to read about Big O notation (possibly [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)). In this particular case,roughly speaking, it means that the memory needed when the algorithm runs is proportional to the product of the length of the two strings, and so is the time